# Getting single thumbnail from Vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to get just the link for a single thumbnail size.

If I call the Vimeo API with

```
/me/albums/xxxxx/videos?pictures.sizes.link
```

then I get just the links, but for all sizes:

```
[pictures] => Array
    (
        [sizes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [link] => https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/592792792_100x75.jpg?r=pad
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [link] => https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/592792792_200x150.jpg?r=pad
                    )

...    
                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [link] => https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/592792792_1280x720.jpg?r=pad
                    )

            )

    )
```

I tried

```
/me/albums/xxxxx/videos?pictures.sizes[3].link
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there any way to request a single size?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can just get back a single image based on their [developer documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/albums/%7Balbum_id%7D/videos).

If you're happy just to get the first link returned you can use [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) which won't care about the index and will just grab the first item:

```
$album = ... // Do whatever it takes get the array in the original question

$first = reset($album['pictures']['sizes'])
$link = $first['link'];
```

If you want a specific item, but you're not sure it exists, you can try with a fallback to reset:

```
$item = isset($album['pictures']['sizes'][3]) ? $album['pictures']['sizes'][3] : reset($album['pictures']['sizes']);
$link = $item['link'];
```

You could also use [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) instead of reset if you prefer a larger image over a smaller one.

Comment: Thanks ... but I'm trying to reduce traffic from API request, so I'm only interested in a way to limit the results from their end...

Comment: Field limitations are described here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats. You can't get specific items in an array, but you can limit the contents of an array. ?fields=pictures.sizes.link will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the sizes parameter. Say for example, if you need the 1024x720 you may specify as ...&sizes=1024

Link for details:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#using-the-sizes-parameter